# while loop is not working c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Below is my code:

I am comparing user input data with existing 2D array. when user enters right user id the programe works fine, but when somebody enters wrong user id then programe crashes.

```
        bool cust=false;
        int row=0;


        do
        {
            cout<<"enter your user id"<<endl;
            cin>>uid;
            cout<<"enter your password"<<endl;
            cin>>upw;

            while(uid!=dataarray[row][3])
            {
                row++;
            }

            if(uid==dataarray[row][3])
            {
                cout<<"found customer"<<endl;
                cust=true;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                cout<<"No customer found"<<endl;
                break;
            }

        }while(!cust);
```

Comment: What do you expect the `while` loop to do, if the `uid` is not in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a limit on your number of rows. Otherwise this call:

```
   while(uid!=dataarray[row][3])
        {
            row++;
        }
```

will crash when you try to access dataarray[30000] and you've only allocated 30000 of them.

Something like:

```
 ...Allocate dataarray with dataarray[MaxNumberOfRows][MaxNumberOfColumns] ... 

 while ((row < MaxNumberOfRows) && (uid!= dataarray[row][3]) { row ++; } 
 if (row == MaxNumberOfRows) {... uid not found... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop has problems:

```
 while(uid!=dataarray[row][3])
 {
    row++;
 }
```

If you input an `uid` which does not exist in your 2D matrix, this while loop will keep running until `row` is out of range and program will crash if you try to access memory not belonging to the 2D matrix. You also need to make sure that `row` will not be larger than total number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

when your uid is not correct, it will go into the while loop:

```
while(uid!=dataarray[row][3])
        {
            row++;
        }
```

if you have no constraint on the value of row, the program will always run in this loop and crash finally.

Answer (score 0):

You do something wrong with the breaks. A `break` makes the program leave the while loop.

So, you should remove the loop in the `else { ... }` clause. You could replace it with a `continue`, which will cause the program to skip to the next execution of the `while` loop.

In fact, the `curl` value is not necessary when you use `break`. When the user enters a good password, the `break` will make it leave the `while` loop and no additional `curl` check is done.

Also, the `int row = 0` should be inside the `while` loop.

Lastly, your inner while-loop will cause the `row` index to go out of bounds for the `dataarray` array. You will have to check that `row` does not cross this maximum.

I'd correct it like this:

```
    do {
        cout<<"enter your user id"<<endl;
        cin>>uid;
        cout<<"enter your password"<<endl;
        cin>>upw;

        int row=0;

        while(row < dataarray.size() - 1 && uid != dataarray[row][3])
        {
            row++;
        }

        if(uid==dataarray[row][3])
        {
            cout<<"found customer"<<endl;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"No customer found"<<endl;
            continue;
        }

    } while(true);
```